# Time of charge of a battery

Tags: battery-charging, time

Given a battery with a certain capacity **C** (in Ah) and given a certain charging current **Ich** (in A), how I can calculate the charging time?

Comment: .. and given the chemistry of the battery, it's also possible to tell if it will blow up or not at given C and I_ch.  What's the battery chemistry?

Comment: By the way, http://batteryuniversity.com is a thorough and systematic web site dedicated to battery issues.  Please read through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charging time depends on a very large number of factors and so capacity and current are insufficient information to make a good calculation. For example, for a typical lead-acid battery you don't charge beyond 75% capacity at a constant current.

You can trade off battery lifetime against charging time. The appropriate charging current isn't arbitrary, A 100 A charging current won't charge a battery 1000 times faster than a 100 mA charging current, in part because heating the battery affects the charging process and capacity.

[image]
<sup>*From [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery)*</sup>

Many people do use a rule of thumb for lead-acid batteries that assume 80% charging efficiency and simply divide capacity in amp-hours by charging current in amps and add about 20%. Realistic charging efficiencies can vary considerably.

See also [Peukert's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law).

For other types of battery chemistry, different rules apply.

Answer (score -1):

Divide C by Ich.
Example: C = 20Ah, I=1A => 20h

Also, charging current might be given as a ratio of C. In this case it would be marked as 0.5C.

Edit: Manufacturers give a C rating = capacity in amp-hours. That says nothing about the actual charge or discharge current. Then they might give a ratio of C for charging and a different figure for discharging.

For example, RC LiPo batteries might have 35C discharge rate and 2C charge rate. So if you have a 2000mAh battery you can discharge it at 70A and charge it at 4A.

For lead-acid ones you typically get crank current (~15C) for a few seconds, normal operation discharge current (might be 1C) and charge current (typically 0.1C).

Comment: Can you explain better "Also, charging current might be given as a ratio of C. In this case it would be marked as 0.5C." Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this the discharge time you have calculated?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Also, the OP clearly says charging current. I don't understand why my answer which is correct and informed is being downvoted.